# moving an object using core motion iPhone

Tags: accelerometer, core-motion, xcode5

I want to be able to move an object in my iphone app using CoreMotion.  If the phone is being tilted forward the object will move down on the screen but if the phone is stopped being tilted, the object will stop. and if the phone is tilted back just a little the object will move up.  I am currently using acceleration.y to move the object up and down but the only way to stop the object moving down is to return the phone to a horizontal position and to make the  object move up the phone needs to be tilted back off the horizonal axis.  Is there a way to compare the previous y position to the current y position and have the object move using the difference between the two.  In other words if the phone it tilted from 45 degrees to 46 then the object will move down but if the phone is tilted back from 45 to 44 then the phone moves up.  Do I use core motion attitude or is there a way to use previous position and current position?

Figured this out use CMDeviceMotion motion.attitude.roll and pitch.